# Eclipse: Can I enable Content Assist "insert best guessed args" by class?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I am using Eclipse 2019-09 R (4.13.0), and Content Assist with "insert best guessed arguments". This works great, apart from log4j logging methods. When I enter the first parenthesis it fills out the longest overloaded method, whereas I really want the single arg method; for example:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    // I want logger.info(String)
    logger.info(null, null, logger, logger, logger, logger, logger, logger, args, logger);
}
```

The best solution I could find so far is to add `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` to Type Filters, but this isn't ideal as it hides the list of available methods.

Is there a way to stop inserting guessed arguments by class? Or perhaps a better workaround than Type Filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that works well for me. I always use the same `logger` var name so I added Java Editor Templates for each of the logging methods, e.g.:

```
Name: logger.info
Automatically insert: yes
Pattern: info("${cursor}");
```

This way I can see the available methods, and **ctrl+space, enter** to auto-complete.